# VSCode / eslint not catching JS const reassign

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, eslint

As you can see, my vscode with vanilla imported airbnb .eslintrc has no problem with trying to reassign a const. When I run the code it rhwos errors but it would be nice to see the error in vscode.

Running on macOS, everything updated.

[image]

Comment: Did you try enabling [the appropriate rule](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-const-assign)?

Comment: So eslint not vscode handles const reassign by default? Wow I’m surprised

Comment: FWIW WebStorm can tell you that's wrong without additional config...

Comment: @jonrsharpe yeah I usually like it but it kills laptop battery

Comment: @danthegoodman vscode doesn't do anything by itself. All syntax and semantics warnings and errors come from plugins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Hi, It does find it and shows it as warning/error based on the rules. So I suspect either you have not not defined it in the rule or the extension is not installed. Can you see other warning/errors in your code?

**PS**: Unfortunately I have to post it in answer as I cannot add image in the comment..

Answer (score 0):

Use **ESLint** plugin.

> VScode cannot detect const reassignment, undeclared function error by default.